# SQL Join multiple matches

Tags: mysql, sql

my problem is that i have 2 Tables:

- Builds (98% Informations are stored here)
- Maps (Each Build is created for a map, these are listed here)
- Votes (Each users Vote for a specific build is stored here)

Now i want to sort the Builds dependent on how many votes they received but if i do a simple LEFT Join i get multiple rows from the same build for each Vote that was given.
Instead i want to Add all the votes up so in the end instead of having:

- Build 72 . . . vote=1
- Build 72 . . . vote=1
- Build 72 . . . vote=-1
- Build 72 . . . vote=1

as a result i would rather have:

- Build 72 . . . vote=2 (Because 1 + 1 + -1 + 1 = 2)

Here is the code i use for Searching/Sorting

```
    $query = sprintf('
        SELECT
            b.*, maps.name AS mapname, votes.vote AS vote
        FROM 
            builds as b
        INNER JOIN
            maps ON maps.id = b.map
        LEFT JOIN
            votes ON votes.fk_build = b.id
        WHERE
            fk_buildstatus = 1 AND
            ' . implode(' ', $set) . ' 1=1
        ORDER BY ' . $by . ' ' . $order . '
        ' . $limitcode);
```

Basically you can ignore everything from WHERE and below, just posted it for completionist sake

(I hope you can understand me and that my question isn't noobish)

Edit: Thanks to the Sum function mentioned in the comments my problem got solved by modifying my query like this:

### Solution!

```
$query = sprintf('
        SELECT
            b.*, maps.name AS mapname, IFNULL(SUM(votes.vote), 0) AS votes
        FROM 
            builds as b
        INNER JOIN
            maps ON maps.id = b.map
        LEFT JOIN
            votes ON votes.fk_build = b.id
        WHERE
            fk_buildstatus = 1 AND
            ' . implode(' ', $set) . ' 1=1
        GROUP BY
            b.id
        ORDER BY ' . $by . ' ' . $order . '
        ' . $limitcode);
```

Comment: Use `sum` function. You will need a subquery to get the sum of votes and then your outer query can get the other columns and the sum from the subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something like this? I couldn't test it because I don't have your data set or table structures.

```
SELECT
            b.*, maps.name AS mapname, SUM(IFNULL(votes.vote,0)) AS vote
        FROM 
            builds as b
        INNER JOIN
            maps ON maps.id = b.map
        LEFT JOIN
            votes ON votes.fk_build = b.id
group by /* Add your group by columns here */
```

Comment: Is group by b.* valid?

Comment: I just created a test table and your right it doesn't work. I updated the answer. Not knowing what columns they wanted to group by I just copied what was in the select.